# Importing github repo as dependency in poetry in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket, python-poetry

Issue:
I am trying to add a bitbucket repo using an ssh key as a tool.poetry.dev.dependency in my pyproject.toml and have it installed in a docker container via docker compose. However, I encounter the following errors (see Errors) when I build the container.

Is there anything that I may be overlooking and/or suggestions to be able to pull a bitbucket repo as a dependency during poetry install in a docker container?

What I have done:

- I know the bitbucket dependency is the issue because when I exchange it to a local path to a whl file instead, the container builds correctly.
- I can install the dependency locally
- I can clone a different repo in the docker container

---

REFERENCES

Errors:
HangupException

The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.

at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dulwich/protocol.py:220 in read_pkt_line

```
   216│ 
   217│         try:
   218│             sizestr = read(4)
   219│             if not sizestr:
 → 220│                 raise HangupException()
   221│             size = int(sizestr, 16)
   222│             if size == 0:
   223│                 if self.report_activity:
   224│                     self.report_activity(4, "read")
```

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:

HangupException

Host key verification failed.

at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dulwich/client.py:1151 in fetch_pack

```
   1147│         with proto:
   1148│             try:
   1149│                 refs, server_capabilities = read_pkt_refs(proto.read_pkt_seq())
   1150│             except HangupException as exc:
 → 1151│                 raise _remote_error_from_stderr(stderr) from exc
   1152│             (
   1153│                 negotiated_capabilities,
   1154│                 symrefs,
   1155│                 agent,
```

My Files/Commands:
pyproject.toml

```
    [tool.poetry.dependencies]

    # Trial 1: I am trying to use ssh key to pull to repo (see docker build command) [1]
    package_name = {git = "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/tenant/repo.git", tag = "v0.0.0"}

    # Trial 2: I don't really want to use http because I don't want to have to feed in credentials [1]
    package_name = {git = "https://user@bitbucket.org/tenant/repo.git", tag = "v0.0.0"}

    # Trial 3: I didn't know if it was just a bitbucket thing so I had also tried with git and it works locally just not in a docker container
    package_name = {git="git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git"}`
```

Dockerfile

```
    ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.2.2
    RUN pip install poetry==$POETRY_VERSION
    COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./
    RUN poetry config installer.max-workers 4 \
        && poetry install --no-root`
```

Docker build command

```
    docker build --no-cache --ssh default -t $IMAGE_NAME .
```

Docker compose command

```
    docker compose build
```

Comment: `Host key verification failed.` means that the SSH could not connect to the server, because it needs an interactive connection to accept the host key of the server (usually happens with y/n prompt). The host key mechanism prevents anyone to spoof your server (man-in-the-middle-attack). The secure way to solve this is to drop the host key to `~/.ssh/known_host`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error thrown at me after trying to install a private package in a container via git. I could get it to work using https instead of ssh.

It might help if you run the install command with `-vvv` to get a more verbose error.

AFAICT, this seems to be an underlying issue with `dulwich`.

If you really don't want to use https, I'd go report this on the corresponding [poetry issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6999), hopefully the poetry team can find a workaround until dulwitch rolls out a fix.